# When is the proper time to instantiate an object?

Tags: php, oop

Is it "better" to instantiate objects as needed or right in the beginning of the code?  Note in the examples one may not need the functionality of *obj2*.

```
obj1 = new Object1();
obj2 = new Object2();

obj1->run;

//lots of code

if (condition) {
    obj2->doThis();
}
```

*OR*

```
obj1 = new Object1();
obj1->run;

//lots of code

if (condition) {
    obj2 = new Object2();
    obj2->doThis();
}
```

Comment: If it does not have any performance impact on your application, then don't worry.

Comment: Would the second example not use less memory if condition is false?

Comment: Yes, but the question is whether it matters or not. If you run into memory issues then use the second way, if not, choose either way. So which of these ways is "better" depends on your situation. If you are not forced to choose one over the other, use the one that makes more sense to you or your co-workers. Code is read more often than written.

Comment: It really depends on the size of the object. If creation does a lot of work, you want to defer it as much as possible. If it's just a simple object waiting for values, go for whatever looks cleaner in your code. Performance hit won't be significant enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just 2 rules**

1. Do not instantiate any object if it's not needed.
2. Instantiate *just before* you need it. And destruct when it's not needed any more.

Unnecessary object creation consumes more memory and makes program run slower. For small projects it'll not make any significant performance difference. But for big projects or long time running Cron it becomes performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Depends: is your time inside inside the if statement more important than time spent at the start of the application? Do you need the object more than once?

If the answer to both questions is no, instantiate the object when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

For readability, I would tend to instantiate closest to when the object is going to be used. I find it easier to remember what `$obj2` is when I see:

```
if (condition) {
    $obj2 = new Object2();
    $obj2->doThis();
}
```

... than if I see

```
if (condition) {
    // $obj2 created 1000lines ago
    // and I forgot all about it
    $obj2->doThis();
}
```

PHP will manage memory by freeing objects no longer in use. So if you have instantiated `new Object1()` and it is no longer needed before `new Object2()` is instantiated, you will have fewer objects in memory.  *But* if you are not experiencing performance problems, this should not be a big concern.

If you were to instantiate lots and lots of objects before actually needing them, monitory your memory consumption and think twice about it...

```
// Need these right away...
for ($i=0; $i<10000000; $i++) {
  $obj1s[] = new Object1();
}

// Don't actually need these until the end of the script
// but built ten million of them anyway...
for ($i=0; $i<10000000; $i++) {
  $obj2s[] = new Object2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

It doesn't particularly matter where *in the global scope* you instantiate an object if you actually need it. Just don't go instantiating objects you won't use.

### Testability answer

*However*, if you want to have the ability to successfully unit test your code you should avoid using the `new` keyword to instantiate objects inside other objects. You should avoid doing things like:

```
class MyClass
{
  public function myMethod()
  {
    $dependency = new DependencyClass; // <--- very bad for testability
    echo $dependency->doSomething();
  }
}

class DependencyClass
{
  public function doSomething()
  {
    return 'did something';
  }
}
```

Instead, your classes should *ask* for their dependencies in the constructor method signature, not *look* for them elsewhere in the code. The better way to do the above would be:

```
class MyClass
{
  protected $dependency;

  public function __construct(DependencyClass $dep)
  {
    $this->dependency = $dep;
  }
  public function myMethod()
  {
    echo $this->dependency->doSomething();
  }
}

$myClass = new MyClass(new DependencyClass); // <-- inject the dependency
```

Comment: If you're looking for extra credit, trying studying up on [the Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: I agree, however my question is more specific about the final object loading than with dependency injection.

Comment: I'm with that, just trying to make a point for people who aren't up with the DI :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to declare the variables at the top (of the function / file), but only instantiate the objects when needed.

```
$ob1;
$obj2;

// some code...

$obj1 = new Object1();
$obj1->run;

// lots of code

if (condition) {
    $obj2 = new Object2();
    $obj2->doThis();
}
```

This allows you to "have your cake and eat it too." Anyone reading your code knows what to expect, because all variables are declared at the start, but you don't waste memory by needlessly instantiating objects.